# How to keep bluetooth connection in background?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, bluetooth

i am writing a bluetooth app communicating with a bluetooth module. Actually it works very well. But i want the connection to stay established also while the app is in background and other apps are used, so that another activity like incoming sms or something else can trigger my app in background to send messages to my device.

Until now i am very confused how to do this. Can anyone give me advice?

I also checked this: [Background Bluetooth App - Threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169539/background-bluetooth-app-threading) but it doesn't help me.

Here is my code so far:
http://pastebin.com/C7Uynuan

Side information: there is a connect button, which establishs the connection and then there are 3 other buttons sending different messages to my device.
In OnResume i reconnect to my device, but this should be not necessary when having a stable connection.

Thanks,

progNewfag

EDIT: Now i am pretty sure that i need to use an IntentService, but not sure how.

Comment: Have you tried Services ?

Comment: Yeah my problem is that i am not sure how to handle an Intentservice so that it doesn't stop. Also the connection between my Intentservice and the gui is confusing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You Have to learn the service first

Here is the Example of Service

Create a new Class and Name it for Exmaple: MyService

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return Null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
        // Do your Bluetooth Work Here
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Now in your main activity you can start the service through this code

```
 startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

For Stopping the service put this code in MainActivity

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

See this Post

[Connection between Activity and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461802/android-connection-between-activity-and-service/23461959#23461959)

Also See this link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-service-tutorial.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/

***EDIT:***

[Example: Communication between Activity and Service using Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/using-localbroadcastmanager-in-service-to-activity-communications/

Comment: Thank you very much. But in the first link they send Strings by adding them to an Intent and call StartService. But how can i send data to my Service while its already running? Because i want a bluetooth connection in my service and then send commands of what it should send over bluetooth.

Comment: And one other question: How can i send data from the service to the activity?

Comment: i tried to start my service with the command above, but my eclipse always says that it would be false and corrects it to this: startService(new Intent());

Comment: if i run it this way i don't see the toast in onCreate, when creating the service. I should be able to see it right?

Comment: If you use only startService(new Intent()); it will not show any toast.

Comment: eclipse error is this: The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MyService>) is undefined ... do you know what's my fault?

Comment: ah i figured it out. I need to write MyActivity.this instead of just this

Comment: Yes you have to write = new intent (MyActivity.this, MyService.class). Did this solves your problem of bluetooth?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59375/discussion-between-prognewfag-and-softcoder).