# how to check Bluetooth device pairing state in background

Tags: android

In android Bluetooth if once any device got paired if we click on device name it will give option as unpair.my doubt is how it is recognising device is in paired state or unpaired state why because in my application also i need same functionality.iam using broadcast receiver to catch events still iam unable to do.any help appreciable.Thanks in advance

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267753/how-to-keep-bluetooth-connection-in-background

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2

Comment: Thank you sasikumar