# Bluetooth while out of app

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to continue to transmit data over Bluetooth while the screen is locked or in another app. If it isn't do I have to store it all on the Bluetooth transmitters end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a service, yes.

Look at this SO answer, and plenty of examples:
[How to keep bluetooth connection in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267753/how-to-keep-bluetooth-connection-in-background)

Also, I believe there's only small set of services that work with BT on background (like music streaming, and others for specific purposes)